# Why xml headers are overlapping specifically in Notepad & working fine in Internet Explorer

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

```
 <FormB1Records>
      <FormB1Details>
        {%- for doc in docData.supportingDocs -%}
        <SupprtingDocBlock>
          <DocumentName>{{ doc.name }}</DocumentName>
          <DocumentType>{{ doc.type }}</DocumentType>
        </SupprtingDocBlock>
        {%- endfor -%}
```

The tags are overlapping and not displaying in a new line.
It displays wel in Internet explorer, but in Notepad - it is overlapped.

The If loop works fine. but the tags inside the for loop seems to have some issue

Comment: this is not an xml problem, more like `\r` or `\n` problem. you should use better tags for your question adding the os and the language you're using

Comment: @diggusbickus can you please help me understand better as I just started with XML and figuring out a solution for it.

Comment: first: maybe i'm wrong (and it happens a lot). with better tags on your question it can attract more knowledgeable people. the actual tags to your question are `xml` and `xml-parsing`, you can change those by editing your question. second: problems with line returns are not xml-specific, a tag with the os you're using (your windows version maybe) would help people to help you. the language you're using to manipulate your template could be relevant too.

Comment: @diggusbickus I was able to work around and got the solution. The issue was with Liquid tags. <? ......?> gets a line break. So by just removing "-" I got the XML tags in seperate lines

Comment: this was a simple problem and had nothing to do with xml parsing, not even xml. if you told from the start you were using liquid someone may have helped you sooner

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around and got the solution. The issue was with Liquid tags.     gets a line break. So by just removing "-" I got the XML tags in seperate lines.

For more clarity, please check this resource :
https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/whitespace/